# Enable assembly binding logging (fusion) on an Azure App Service (Web App/Websites)?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, fusion, ysod

Just wondering if anyone can tell me the process for turning on binding logging for a YSOD that is happening on Azure App Service?

As far as I know there isn't any direct access that would permit registry editing or running fuslogvw (?); can the log file be retrieved to run the viewer on it locally? Do we have to code something in an AssemblyResolve event?

Answer (score 0):

Under application settings, you can add WEBSITE_FUSIONLOGGING_ENABLED and set the value to 1. There will be a [blog post](https://azure.github.io/AppService/) on this momentarily, so be on the lookout. Once enabled, you can navigate to offending page and the YSOD will display the FUSLOGVW log results. This setting only works ASP.NET Framework, so if your application is ASPNETCORE, this won't work. If this setting doesn't work, it may not have been rolled out to your region yet.

Comment: Do you know any region that has already this parameter effective? I'd deploy to it just to fix the issue and redeploy back to mine.